# Can't download images if I call the FileResult function from a void

Tags: c#

I have a `button` inside a `form` to download an image.

If the form calls a `FileResult` function, the image downloads perfectly.
If the form calls a `void` function, the image downloads but I have this error:

> Photos cannot open this file because the format is not currently supported, or the file is corrupted

If I call this function, that calls the function that download the image, I have the error I showed you.

```
public void DescargarImagen(string imagenSelec, string labelOculto)
        {
            try
            {
                Logger.Debug("IMAGEN SELECCIONADA ---> " + imagenSelec);
                Logger.Debug("LABEL OCULTO ---> " + labelOculto);

                switch (labelOculto)
                {
                    case "imgIndividual":
                        Logger.Debug("ENTRA EN IMAGEN INDIVIDUAL");
                        DescargarImagenIndividual(imagenSelec);
                        break;
                    case "FrenteDni":
                        Logger.Debug("ENTRA EN FRENTE DNI");
                        DescargarImagenFrenteDni(imagenSelec);
                        break;
                    case "DorsoDni":
                        Logger.Debug("ENTRA EN DORSO");
                        DescargarImagenDorsoDni(imagenSelec);
                        break;
                }
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message + " || Funcion: DescargarImagen()");
            ViewData["ERROR"] = ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is the function to download an image

```
   public FileResult DescargarImagenIndividual(string imagenSelec)
    {
        string consulta, ruta = "";
        string[] splitImg;

        Logger.Debug("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Logger.Debug("IMAGEN SELECCIONADA LLEGADA DESCARGAR IMAGEN INDIVIDUAL: " + imagenSelec);
        try
        {
            splitImg = imagenSelec.Split("/");
            using MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GlobalVariables.connectionSQL);
            connection.Open();
            // /temporal/[img]
            consulta = "SELECT Path FROM Entrega WHERE Path LIKE '%" + splitImg[2] + "%'";
            Logger.Debug("CONSULTA IMAGEN INDIVIDUAL: " + consulta);
            using MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ruta = "wwwroot/" + reader["Path"].ToString();
            }

            string contentType = "image/png";
            byte[] bites = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition",
                $"attachment; filename=\"Imagen Entrega.jpg\"");

            Logger.Debug("Descarga imagen individual || DescargarImagenIndividual()");
            return File(bites, contentType);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message + " || Funcion: DescargarImagenIndividual()");
            ViewData["ERROR"] = ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public FileResult DescargarImagen(string imagenSelec, string labelOculto)
            {
                FilResult fr = null;
                try
                {    
                    switch (labelOculto)
                    {
                        case "imgIndividual":                                
                            return DescargarImagenIndividual(imagenSelec);
                            
                        case "FrenteDni":                                
                            return DescargarImagenFrenteDni(imagenSelec);

                        case "DorsoDni":                               
                            return DescargarImagenDorsoDni(imagenSelec);

                    }

return fr;
                }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).